# Save chart image in specific location GWT

Tags: javascript, image, gwt, save, google-visualization

I have the following code to save an image from my google chat:

My HMTL:

```
   function getImgData(chartContainer) 
   {
        var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('iframe')
[0].contentDocument.getElementById('chartArea');
   
        var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
        var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
        var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);
    
    
        canvas.setAttribute(
            'style',
            'position: absolute; ' +
            'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
            'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
        doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
        canvg(canvas, svg);
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
        return imgData;
  }
  
  function saveAsImg(chartContainer) 
  {
      var data = getImgData(chartContainer);
      window.location = data.replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
  }
```

The problem is that I need to ask the user the location. I would like to save it straight. I mean, without asking any specific location, but I need this location afterwards on server side to include this image into a pdf file.

So I need to know the location and I need to do it transparent to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to save the image on your server instead of on the client-side?  If so, you will need a service on your server that can accept the image in an upload and save it as a file.  Then you can send the image via AJAX with something like this:

```
function uploadImage (chartContainer) {
    // using jQuery AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/image/save/service',
        data: {
            image: getImgData(chartContainer)
        },
        type: 'POST'
    });
}
```

This probably needs tweaking to get exactly right, but the basic concepts are in place.